# Efficient conversion of an array into a two-dimensional one using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, multidimensional-array

I want to do the below in a performant way in C#, preferably using LINQ.

`Array[Length]` to `Array[Length/Row][Row]`  where `Row` and `Length` are variables.

Comment: Could you give an example of how the data you are trying to convert looks?

Comment: LINQ-to-Objects deals with IEnumerable's, not directly with arrays. Two-dimensional arrays are not really supported at all.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Buffer.BlockCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy.aspx) to efficiently convert between n-dimensional arrays of [blittable types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75dwhxf7.aspx):

```
int[] a = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

int rows = 2;
int columns = a.Length / rows;
int[,] b = new int[columns, rows];

Buffer.BlockCopy(a, 0, b, 0, sizeof(int) * a.Length);

// b[0, 0] == 1
// b[0, 1] == 2
// b[1, 0] == 3
// b[1, 1] == 4
// b[2, 0] == 5
// b[2, 1] == 6
```

This takes advantage of the fact that multi-dimensional (*not* jagged!) arrays are laid out continuously in memory by the CLR.

For non-blittable types, simply use some good ol' `for` loops.

Answer (score 1):

That's not a two dimensional array, that's a jagged array. I assume that you mean `Array[Length/Row,Row]`.

There isn't anything in LINQ that does exactly that, so you will have a bit of overhead if you want to use it. The most performant way is straight forward code:

```
public T[,] MakeRows<T>(T[] values, int rowSize) {
  T[,] result = new T[values.Length / rowSize, rowSize];
  int row = 0, col = 0;
  foreach (T value in values) {
    resul[row, col] = value;
    if (++col == rowsize) {
      col = 0;
      row++;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Note: The method assumes that the items are evenly divisable into rows.